# Does $\delta$ have to be less then $\epsilon$ for uniform continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Does $\delta$ have to be less than $\epsilon$ for uniform continuity?
If not, what is the implication of $\delta < \epsilon$ in a uniform continuity proof?

Comment: Do you have a definition of uniform continuity you could check? Does it contain any notation that requires $\delta<\varepsilon$?

Comment: In general, $\delta$ does not need to be less than $\varepsilon$.  This is likely some condition in the specific example that you're considering.  In general, in uniform continuity, $\delta$ will be bounded by some function of $\varepsilon$ independent of the corresponding point in the domain.

Comment: What if your function is constant? Then it's uniformly continuous but any delta at all will work.

Comment: Perhaps providing more details, such as including the specific problem, will provide you with a better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this assumption since if $\delta_1$ is *good* for uniform continuity then so is every $0<\delta_2<\delta_1$. However "the best you can do" mean finding the biggest values of $\delta$ for which the condition of uniform continuity is satisfied and this $\delta$ may be and may be not smaller than $\epsilon$: just think of functions $f(x)=ax$ for $a<1$ and $a>1$ (say, positive).